# Dovecot Authentication with MySQL and Horde Webmail

Tags: dovecot, imap, webmail

I am looking into setting up my web server to have its own IMAP/POP/SMTP server.

For the IMAP and POP3 and I am using Dovecot and the webmail I am using Horde.

Its all mostly working, I can connect to the imap and pop server, and I can send emails, and horde shows the emails in the inbox.

The problem I am having is at the moment there seems to be a bit of a disconnect between between Horde and Dovecot.

At the moment, if I create a new user inside horde, before they can give the inbox, I first of all need log in to my web server and create a user using useradd, specifying the directory, creating the Maildir directory within the home user directory and set the password for the account.

What I am wanting to do, instead of having to do multiple different steps, e.g. create user in horde, create user in linux, I want it all to be done together, i.e. I create the user in horde, and I don't need to do anything else, the inbox directory is all created without needing to do anything else.

Comment: hope this will help... http://wiki.horde.org/FAQ/Admin/Config#toc13

Comment: I do not know enough about horde to know how it runs from the server, but I think you should create a script that takes care of this backend user creation. Whenever a horde user is created, then a script is executed. The script would of course, check if that user exists, add the user with desired password, create the home directory, and create the Maildir directory.

Comment: @ElixirofLove That's a good idea, I'll give that a try

Comment: @Boardy If that is a valid answer for you I can go ahead and submit it if you would like. I am continuing my research on horde though.